# Firebase error when running app in other machine

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface, sha1

I'm facing a weird error, when other people run my Android app in their machines they get this error

```
"09-30 23:31:17.447 16756-16756/com.example.luthiers.capstone E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.UserCancellationException: Unknown error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:101)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:128)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)"
```

Also this error:

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Code: 16, message: 16:
at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:106)
at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.AuthMethodPickerActivity.onActivityResult(AuthMethodPickerActivity.java:242)
```

I've done a lot of research and people say that it's because they have to put their SHA-1 on the Firebase settings, however this seems wierd, since before people didn't get this errors, and also I don't seem apropiate to have all those SHA-1 fingerprints on the project.
What is happening and how can I solve this error?

By the way I'm using the following libraries

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    // For Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    // For Firebase Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    // For Firebase Storage (pictures)
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    // For Firebase Messaging
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    // For UI
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
    // For Firebase Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    // For Firebase Performance
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    // For Firebase Background logic
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
```

the only sign in method enabled is the Google authenticator

Comment: Have you also added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'`?

Comment: yes, does that causes a conflict?

Comment: No, it definitely should be there. I've asked you because I haven't seen it in your question. Please share your entire file. Are you also sure that you have enabled authentication in your Firebase Console?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to add the following line of code right after the existing dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi Andrea! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?